# how to use DumpBin.exe for getting mangled names

Tags: c#, dllimport, name-mangling, dumpbin

Hi I've created a C++ DLL which I import to C# application to re-use a function.
the function code in C++ is `static bool IsSomethingAttached(char *Arg1[])`

When I use DllImport as below in C# program,
[DllImport("DllName")]
I get the error as EntryPointNotFound exception.

I used

> `**DumpBin /symbols Dllname.dll**` for getting the mangled name.

1) But I do not know how to exactly get the mangled name. Few posts say we should use /exports but `/exports` instead of `/symbols` just give the summary and I do not get mangled name. Pl help

2) How to use ***undname.exe*** to get the decorated name from undecorated name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

`/ALL` Displays all available information except code disassembly. Use the /DISASM option to display disassembly. You can use `/RAWDATA:NONE` with the `/ALL` option to omit the raw binary details of the file.
Because the `/ALL` option is simply a combination of all the other options, an example is not needed.

you can use `exports` and `.def` file in C++ to get undecorated name in c#. here no need of the dumpBin